# Isolated "Semantic-Release" docker container works, but takes 40 minutes in GitLab CI

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, containers, semantic-release

I have an isolated Gitlab server and Gitlab runner that lack internet connectivity. I am trying to run "semantic-versioning" (a node.js app) in a Docker container so that it can handle automatic versioning for my GitLab repositories.

I have to build all the dependencies into a Docker container in advanced since they cannot reach the internet during runtime, and I have to manually move the container over to the Gitlab Runner for a manual Docker load.

I have gotten through all the token issues and connected all the parts together, and I finally got a positive result (with a minor version bump), however it took 1660 seconds to run on a nearly empty repository (this repo is just for test).

The step that takes up the most time and where the process hangs is when "npx semantic-release" is executed. From there it can take up to 40 minutes to finish. However, once the npx semantic-release step finishes, the actual "work" of analyzing the repo takes just a few seconds. This makes me think it has something more to do with how the Dockerfile was prepped than a configuration issue with semantic-release itself.

This is the step below that is taking the longest:

**$ npx semantic-release**

**npx: installed 575 in 1660.75s**

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
Using docker image sha256:d0733317abd6fbce07dcf85b1aff35d82f986e7de9ff56fdf5b985504bf3e9f4 for semantic:1 ...
$ npx semantic-release
npx: installed 575 in 1660.75s
[6:03:29 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Running semantic-release version 17.4.4
[6:03:29 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "verifyConditions" from "@semantic-release/gitlab"
[6:03:29 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "analyzeCommits" from "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
[6:03:29 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "generateNotes" from "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
[6:03:29 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "publish" from "@semantic-release/gitlab"
[6:03:29 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Run automated release from branch main on repository http://gitlab-ci-token:[secure]@[internal_IP]/gitlab-instance-937dde58/my_second_project.git
[6:03:30 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Allowed to push to the Git repository
[6:03:30 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/gitlab"
[6:03:30 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/gitlab] › ℹ  Verify GitLab authentication (http://[internal_IP]/api/v4)
[6:03:30 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/gitlab"
[6:03:30 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Found git tag v1.0.0 associated with version 1.0.0 on branch main
[6:03:30 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Found 32 commits since last release
[6:03:30 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "analyzeCommits" of plugin "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
[6:03:30 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analyzing commit: new stuff
```

Likely its my Dockerfile that needs further inspecting. However I am quite new at it and would need advice on whats taking so long (can I not have the dockerfile just pre-install the 575 dependencies for semantic-release in advance?)

Here is my Dockerfile (which I built as "*semantic:1*")

```
FROM node:13
RUN npm config set strict-ssl false
RUN npm install semantic-release@17.4.4
RUN npm install @semantic-release/gitlab@6.2.2
```

Here is my gitlab-ci.yml

```
--- 
release: 
  image: "semantic:1"
  only: 
    refs: 
      - main
      - alpha
      - "/^(([0-9]+)\\.)?([0-9]+)\\.x/"
      - "/^([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)(?:-([0-9A-Za-z-]+(?:\\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*))?(?:\\+[0-9A-Za-z-]+)?$/"
  script: 
    - "npx semantic-release"
  stage: release
stages: 
  - release
```

and my .releaserc.yml

```
plugins:
  - "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
  - "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
  - "@semantic-release/gitlab"
branches:
  - "main"
  - "+([0-9])?(.{+([0-9]),x}).x"
  - name: "alpha"
    prerelease: "alpha"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to this repo:
https://github.com/caos/semantic-release

Basically just looked at that person's Dockerfile, and just added in strict versions so that there would be no searching for the latest update (since my setup is isolated).

```
FROM node:13
RUN npm config set strict-ssl false
RUN npm install -g semantic-release@17.4.5
RUN npm install -g @semantic-release/gitlab@6.2.2
RUN npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
ENTRYPOINT ["npx"]
CMD ["semantic-release@17.4.5"]
```

Cheers!